# Get a list of folders that contain at least one file

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt, directory-structure

There is a directory structure, from which I need to list all the folders, which contains at least one file. So when a folder contains just subfolders, it shouldn't be listed.
I tried following commands for this, but both are listing also directories without any files.

```
dir /s /b /o:n /ad > f.txt

for /r %a in (.) do @if exist "%~fa\*.*" echo %~fa >> f2.txt
```

**UPDATE**:
I tried also this command:

```
for /r /d %a in (.) do @(dir /s /b /a-d "%a\*" >nul 2>&1 && echo %~fa)
```

Folder structure:

```
C:.
└───T1
    ├───T2
    └───T3
            test.txt
```

Output of command:

```
C:\_privat\teszt
C:\_privat\teszt\T1
C:\_privat\teszt\T1\T3
```

Expected output:

```
C:\_privat\teszt\T1\T3
```

Comment: What about folders that contain non-empty subfolders? It doesn't contain files, just folders, but one or more of those subfolders may contain files. According to your description, it shouldn't be listed. Is that correct?

Comment: @Stephan : No, that should be listed also. After that these paths will be input of a file processing application. Thanks, that you mentioned this case!

Answer (score 1):

Use `for` switch `/D` to process folders only (which makes it much faster). Use `dir /s /a-d` to list only files in that folder and below. Skip the output (we don't need it) and echo depending on success (no file found) or failure (at least one file found).

This is a generic code (to show all possibilities), just remove the parts you don't need:

```
for /r /d %a in (.) do @(dir /s /b /a-d "%a\*" >nul 2>&1 && echo + %~fa || echo - %~fa)
```

Comment: Thanks, but its output is nearly the same as I got earlier, either way I change  parts of it. Folders which contains just subfolders appear in output.

Comment: the output is very different. You noticed the `-` and `+` in the output? Just remove the `echo` part that you don't want. (When I understand your question correctly, remove `|| echo - %~fa` and the `+` from the other echo).

Comment: I see and I tried it, but that list also contains folders without any files.

Comment: It doesn't for me. Can you show me? (edit your output either into my answer or into your question (mabe also the output of `tree /f`) - it will be unreadable in a comment)